# What is the issue in checking blank array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a query like following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member_details WHERE blood_group = 'O+'";
```

if I will execute this query in phpmyadmin then i will get zero rows.
But when I echo the array then i am getting like following.

```
$n = new data();

$res = $n -> querySend($sql);

$abc = mysql_fetch_array($res); 

//if i do like this
   echo $res;  // output getting as Resource id#6

//if i do like this then
   echo count($abc); // output getting as 1

//if i do like this then
   print_r($abc); die; // output getting as blank
```

I want to check whether `$abc` is empty or not.
But due to above outputs I am not able to check it.
Can any one tell me whats the issue with this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: `if i do like this` ? that's not a valid syntax.

Comment: Yes. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check with [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), like:

```
if( is_array($abc) ) {
   echo "It is array";
}
```

And, btw, you should be doing

```
if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0 ) {
    $abc = mysql_fetch_array($res);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  check using

```
 if(empty($abc))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching from mysql_* to mysqli_* or PDO, Mysql_* is deprecated and will not work in future versions of php.

What you can do in this case tho, is check num_rows of the result before fetching the array:
https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows (i know, mysql_* function, but warnings are on the page! ).